# Print_r() con salto de linea por elemento de Array

Tags: php, array

### He estado mirando alguna pregunta del estilo a esta pero no he visto nada que me sirva, por ello os expongo mi duda.

Tengo un objeto llamado `$detalle` que tiene un array con otros arrays dentro (perdón, pero no recuerdo el nombre de este tipo de array) y los datos los escribo mediante `print_r()` y `file_put_contents()` en un archivo llamado `detallesPedido.txt`.

Este es el código que utilizo:

```
$contenido = print_r($detalle, true);

file_put_contents("detallesPedido.txt", $contenido);
```

Mi problema es que en el archivo `detalles.txt` me muestra todos los datos en una misma linea y no consigo que cada elemento del array se muestre en una linea.

He intentado utilizar el `fwrite()` pero me seguía sucediendo lo mismo.

**EDIT**: Siguiendo el comentario de @A.Cedano me gustaría que se mostrará de la siguiente forma:

```
Array ( 
[a] => manzana 
[b] => banana 
[c] => Array ( 
   [0] => x 
   [1] => y 
   [2] => z )
```

Realmente el sangrado es un poco indiferente, pero si que sea algo así como una "lista".

**EDIT2**: He probado con un array mas simple.

```
array( 'mensaje'=>"el correo se ha enviado", 
       'datos'=> "m");
```

Y sigue saliendo en linea, en vez de como correspondería a `print_r`.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de cómo quieres que se escriban los datos en el archivo? `print_r` te saca los datos así: `Array
(
    [a] => manzana
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)`

Comment: He reproducido tu problema del siguiente modo: `$detalle= array(
               'mensaje'=>"el correo se ha enviado",
      'datos'=> array(
                'nombre' => "n",
                'correo' => "e",
                'mensaje' => "m"
    ),
              'respuesta' => "true"
     );
       
 $contenido = print_r($detalle, true);
 file_put_contents("detallesPedido.txt", $contenido);` y en el archivo los datos se escriben bien, tal y como salen en pantalla cuando se usa `print_r`. No sé entonces cuál es el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada decirte que tu archivo de texto en realidad tiene el formato que deseas solo que cuando lo abres con el editor de texto de Windows el no lo ve así. Puedes probarlo abrirlo con Word o con otro editor y verificarás lo que te digo. El problema es que algunos editores interpretan los saltos de línea más flexibles que otros. Por tanto Notepad espera que cada salto de línea termine con los caracteres CR, LF (0x0d, 0x0a) y si solo encuentra uno de ellos no lo representa como deseas. La solución es reemplazar en el texto que quieres almacenar en el archivo todos los saltos de línea por la constante **PHP_EOL** que en dependencia del Sistema Operativo en el que estes asigna el valor indicado para que tu editor reconozca el salto de línea correctamente. Aquí te dejo el código:

```
$data = [
    'person' => [
        ['name' => 'dariel', 'age' => 27],
        ['name' => 'mily', 'age' => 24]
    ],
    'animal' => [
        ['name' => 'Floppy']
    ]
];

$contenido = print_r($data, true);
//Aqui es donde hago el reemplazo que comenté arriba
file_put_contents("arreglo.txt", preg_replace("/\n/", PHP_EOL, $contenido));
```

Espero que te haya servido de algo!!! Saludos

Comment: Justamente. Ha sido cambiarlo y perfecto. Muchas gracias!

Comment: No hay de que :P